# How can I get the background of my sticky table th to not scroll away?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have this table that dynamically loads the table body rows.
The wrapper uses Bootstrap5's overflow-scroll to allow for the table to stay one height and scroll if too many rows are generated.
Now I made the table head sticky but in order to accommodate chromium I also had to apply it to each individual `thead th`

Now the issue is on chromium while the `thead th` text is sticky the background color is not, so it scrolls away! This works fine on firefox

```css
#thead_presets{

    /* background: white; */
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);

}


.chrome_sticky{

    background: white;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overflow-scroll" style="height:350px;width: 855px;"
  <table class="table" id="preset_table" style="text-align: center;" >
    <thead id="thead_presets">
      <tr class="chrome_sticky">
        <th class="chrome_sticky" scope="col">Name</th>
        <th class="chrome_sticky" scope="col">ISO</th>
        <th class="chrome_sticky" scope="col">AV</th>
        <th class="chrome_sticky" scope="col">TV</th>
        <th class="chrome_sticky" scope="col">Light 1</th>
        <th class="chrome_sticky" scope="col">Light 2</th>
        <th class="chrome_sticky" scope="col">Light 3</th>
        <th class="chrome_sticky" colspan="2" scope="col">Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="preset_table_body">
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I closed several opening tags. See if that helps using the snippet below:

```css
#thead_presets {
  /* background: white; */
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.chrome_sticky {
  background: white;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overflow-scroll" style="height:350px;width: 855px;">
  <table class="table" id="preset_table" style="text-align: center;">
    <thead id="thead_presets">
      <tr class="chrome_sticky">
        <th class="chrome_sticky" scope="col">Name</th>
        <th class="chrome_sticky" scope="col">ISO</th>
        <th class="chrome_sticky" scope="col">AV</th>
        <th class="chrome_sticky" scope="col">TV</th>
        <th class="chrome_sticky" scope="col">Light 1</th>
        <th class="chrome_sticky" scope="col">Light 2</th>
        <th class="chrome_sticky" scope="col">Light 3</th>
        <th class="chrome_sticky" colspan="2" scope="col">Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="preset_table_body">
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry when I copied the code some of the closing tags were messed up in the paste however that is not the issue in the source code it's browser-specific.